# Entry point not found in assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, appdomain, .net-assembly

I have a Application where I need to create AppDomain and Load Assembly into it and execute the methods in the Assembly.

Here is my Code

```
public class CreateAppDomain
{
     public void CreateAppDom()
        {
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myDomain");
        domain.ExecuteAssembly(@"C:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\A1\A1\bin\Debug\A1.dll");
        domain.CreateInstanceFrom(@"C:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\A1\A1\bin\Debug\A1.dll","A1.Navigate");
        }

}
```

I above code is written in a classfile called CreateAppDomain.cs

In my Default.aspx page I created the instance of the above class and called the create method.Here is the code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateAppDomain obj = new CreateAppDomain();
        obj.CreateAppDom();
        Response.Write("Application Domain Successfully created");
    }
```

when I run the default.aspx page I get a error saying

Entry point not found in assembly 'A1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Can Anyone explain me the meaning of above error and solution to it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly()` method loads an assembly into specified domain and then executes it's standard entry point i.e. `static void Main(string[] args)` method.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173139%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for details.

What do you want is probably one of the overloads of [`CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createinstanceandunwrap.aspx)

EDIT:

I created ConsoleApplication9, added besides ClassLibrary1. In the ClassLibrary1 I have `Class1`:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1 : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void Go()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My AppDomain's FriendlyName is: {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        }
    }
}
```

In the ConsoleApplication9 these's:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Trying to run method in current domain...");
    var inCurrentDomain = new Class1();
    inCurrentDomain.Go();

    Console.WriteLine("\nTrying to run method in remote domain...");
    string asmName = typeof(Class1).Assembly.FullName;
    string typeName = typeof (Class1).FullName;
    Console.WriteLine("Class1's assembly name is: {0}\nType name: {1}", asmName, typeName);

    var remoteDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("My remote domain");
    var remoteObject = (Class1)remoteDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(asmName, typeName);
    Console.WriteLine("\nRemote instance created. Running Go() method:");
    remoteObject.Go();
}
```

When run, I have:

> ```
> Trying to run method in current domain...
> My AppDomain's FriendlyName is: ConsoleApplication9.exe
>
> Trying to run method in remote domain...
> Class1's assembly name is: ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
> Type name: ClassLibrary1.Class1
>
> Remote instance created. Running Go() method:
> My AppDomain's FriendlyName is: My remote domain
> ```

Comment: Yes but you don't have the static void Main in .dlls it's just in applications(CLI or GUI),eg. .exe files.

Comment: You're right. Entry point is set in the metadata and could be changed. In any case it is not what OP wants as far as I've understood. He wants to create some instance in the remote domain and call it, not execute some single method whatever it named.

Comment: Thanx.. I tried using CreateInstanceAndUnwrap() instead of createInstanceFrom() but no luck I get the same error

Comment: I've just updated my answer. My guess is that you pass AssemblyName and/or type name incorrectly. My example has direct reference from console app to library, but it is not required. You just can't cast returned result to concrete class if you have no reference.