# Data Migration Command in EFCore fails

Tags: entity-framework, migration

I am unable to run this command: "dotnet ef migration add". I get the error message "Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.". 
I have come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404704/entry-point-not-found-in-assembly), but it doesnt seem to solve my problem. 
Below is my project.json file.

```
     "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "ReportBook.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "ReportBook.Repository": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0",
    "Repository.Pattern.EFCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "ReportBook.Service": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.1",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection": "1.0.0-alpha2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq": "1.0.3",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-rc2",
    "SimpleIdentityServer.Authentication.Common": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
    "IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation": "1.0.1-rc2",
    "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates": "4.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.1"
     },
     "frameworks": {

      "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
    },
     "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
    },
      "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
        "System.GC.Server": true
      }
       },
      "scripts": {
        "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder    %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
     },
     "tools": {
       "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
       "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
     }
   }
```

Comment: I get the same error just by doing a scaffold-dbcontext. As no more information is provided it is quite complicated to debug!

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, were you able to resolve?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I took the whole application down and started all over step by step. So I really cant tell what went wrong